# Lenovo Ideapad 100 doesn't start

Tags: laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop

As the computer person in the family I've been handed a non-working Lenovo Ideapad 100 in the hope that I can bring it back to life.

The machine is a Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD (with an AZERTY keyboard)

So far, when I press the power-on button, all I get is a big Lenovo logo (I don't see indications such as "). From time to time I can hear the CD drive rattle (trying to boot on that?).

The Lenovo site says that pressing Fn+F2 during power-on will get me to the BIOS , but this doesn't work (possibly related to the missing instructions at the bottom of the screen)

Also found the "Novo" button, but if the behavior is different when I press it (on power-on, the screen lights up, then goes dark, and then lights up again) this doesn't make much difference in the end.

It is possible that this machine has been unused for a long while after being found broken and that the battery is currently depleted (or even dead)...

It may have been dropped because one of the screen hinges has a lot of play.

Any ideas to move forward before I open the machine to see if some connector needs to be reseated?

Comment: Is it also possible that that Laptop Personal Computer has been left out in the rain and that some near forest fires might have tampered it? How long has passed since you have bought it? Is the incorporated keyboard still working? There was another person on this Web-Site who in the end discovered that his 2,011 Laptop Personal Computer had keys that were difficult to press.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Said family member bought it new a long while ago.

Comment: The other person on this Web-Site has had a similar difficulty into entering the B.I.O.S. Eventually, he realized that the keys were simply difficult to press. After a few years (how many in your case?), it is possible that the built-in keyboard got stuck. Try again a few times.